# Google map autocomplete get LatLngBound?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

how to get latlngbound in places get by autocomplete?

for getting latitude i use the following code

```
var place = places.getPlace();
var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
```

However it is not working when i try following code to get latlngbounds

```
// northeast is undefined
var latlngbounds = place.geometry.bounds.northeast.lat();

// undefined
var latlngbounds = place.geometry.bounds;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PlaceGeometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry) also includes a suggested viewport, which is a google.maps.LatLngBounds object.  (Its name is viewport, not bounds, however)

```
Properties  Type    Description
location    LatLng  The Place's position.
viewport    LatLngBounds    The preferred viewport when displaying this Place on a map. This property will be null if the preferred viewport for the Place is not known.
```

```
var place = places.getPlace();
var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
var bounds = place.geometry.viewport;
```